# The height of text view doesn't change dynamically

Tags: android, xml

I wrote an android program. in the right hand there are 4 little green boxes (text view). I set their height as wrap to dynamically change height and cover the whole layout and if I add extra textview the height decrease.

**Graphic:**

[image: Graphic]

**layout_file.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="300dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="0.75 ">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="0.25">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="#00ffff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="#00ff00" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_margin="2dip"
        android:background="#00ffff" android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_margin="2dip"
        android:background="#00ffff" android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dib" android:layout_weight="0.25">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="#00ffff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:background="#00ff00" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="300dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="0.25">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dip"
        android:layout_margin="2dip"
        android:background="#00ff00" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:background="#00ff0b" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:background="#00ff0b" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:background="#00ff0b" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:background="#00ff0b" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Java code:**

```
package abc.sara.app.mystartu1;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;

  public class mystartup1 extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your Java code ?

Comment: You have nested nested nested weights, you need to rethink your layout. I would start with that

Comment: @PranitBankar which java code?

Comment: You said that you have written an android program. That would be Java+XML. You have displayed the XML code. But you also would have written the Java code that would make the TextView change its parameters. Add that code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well okey I finally found your problem. Try to play more around with the weights and TextViews.

- Set your all your right, green TextViews to `android:layout_height="match_parent"`
- Set all weights to `android:layout_weight="1"`
- Set the highest to `android:layout_weight="0.7"`

Now it should look like that:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="#00ff0b"
        android:layout_weight="0.7" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="#00ff0b"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="#00ff0b"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="#00ff0b"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="#00ff0b"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: yes you can see that at the end of the code I have for textveiw and in each one I set             android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: I edited my answer. Please rate it and give me feedback.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity:

```
TextView textview;
textview = (TextView)findviewbyid(R.id.textview1);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams Params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(25,50);
textview .setLayoutParams(Params1);  


//try this
```

Answer (score 0):

first get layout height dynamically

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.YOUD VIEW ID);
ViewTreeObserver vto = layout.getViewTreeObserver(); 
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onGlobalLayout() { 
        this.layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); 
        int width  = layout.getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = layout.getMeasuredHeight(); 

    } 
});
```

then change your TextView height by logic implementing to calculate and fit to screen as:

```
LayoutParams params = textView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 70;
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```